# Google charts line graph: Tooltip Hitbox

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I created this line graph with the google charts library.
I want the tooltip to show up, once a user gets near to the line (e.g. in the red circle). Right now it pops up only if I move the mouse directly onto the point. Is there a way to enlargen the "hitbox"?

[image]

Comment: nothing out of the box, you would have to add something custom.

Answer (score 3):

google charts does not provide an option to increase the "hitbox"

but they do provide methods we can use to add our own custom hitbox

basically, we have to track the mouse ourselves and determine if the mouse is within our pre-defined range
if found within the range, then we select the point so the tooltip will be shown
as such, we have to add the following option,
to allow the tooltip to be shown "on hover" and "on select"

```
tooltip: {
  trigger: 'both'
}
```

in the following, **rough** example, I've set the hit range as...

10% of the x-axis value
40% of the y-axis value

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['controls', 'corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y'],
    [10, 15],
    [15, 13],
    [18, 20],
    [24, 26],
    [34, 30],
    [40, 43],
    [49, 48],
    [50, 55],
    [65, 67],
    [70, 70],
    [72, 70],
    [73, 70],
    [80, 85]
  ]);

  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
      top: 32,
      left: 32,
      right: 16,
      bottom: 32
    },
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    legend: {
      position: 'top'
    },
    selectionMode: 'multiple',
    tooltip: {
      trigger: 'both'
    }
  };

  // create chart
  var container = document.getElementById('chart');
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);

  // set hit range
  var xHitRange = 0.10;  // 10% of x-axis
  var yHitRange = 0.40;  // 40% of y-axis

  // wait for chart to draw
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    // get chart layout
    var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();

    // get chart bounds
    var chartBounds = container.getBoundingClientRect();

    // listen for mouse move
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
      var xAxisValue;
      var yAxisValue;

      // mouse coordinates
      var xCoord = e.pageX;
      var yCoord = e.pageY;

      // clear currect selection
      chart.setSelection([]);

      // determine if mouse is within chart area
      if ((xCoord >= chartBounds.left) && (xCoord <= (chartBounds.left + chartBounds.width)) &&
          (yCoord >= chartBounds.top) && (yCoord <= (chartBounds.top + chartBounds.height))) {
        // determine axis values of mouse location
        xAxisValue = chartLayout.getHAxisValue(xCoord - chartBounds.left);
        yAxisValue = chartLayout.getVAxisValue(yCoord - chartBounds.top);

        // find points within the hit range
        var pointsFound = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
          var xRowValue = data.getValue(i, 0);
          var yRowValue = data.getValue(i, 1);

          var xRangeMin = xRowValue - (xRowValue * xHitRange);
          var xRangeMax = xRowValue + (xRowValue * xHitRange);

          var yRangeMin = yRowValue - (yRowValue * yHitRange);
          var yRangeMax = yRowValue + (yRowValue * yHitRange);

          if ((xAxisValue >= xRangeMin) && (xAxisValue <= xRangeMax) &&
              (yAxisValue >= yRangeMin) && (yAxisValue <= yRangeMax)) {
            pointsFound.push(i);
          }
        }

        // determine if points were found
        if (pointsFound.length > 0) {
          // find point closest to the mouse
          pointsVariance = [];
          pointsFound.forEach(function (row) {
            var xRowValue = data.getValue(row, 0);
            var yRowValue = data.getValue(row, 1);
            var xVariance = Math.abs(xAxisValue - xRowValue);
            var yVariance = Math.abs(yAxisValue - yRowValue);
            pointsVariance.push(xVariance + yVariance);
          });
          var minVariance = null;
          pointsVariance.forEach(function (variance) {
            minVariance = minVariance || variance;
            minVariance = Math.min(minVariance, variance);
          });

          // show tooltip of closest point
          chart.setSelection([{row: pointsFound[pointsVariance.indexOf(minVariance)], column: 1}]);
        }
      }
    });
  });
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```